# Azure Pipeline artifacts do not show under Storage

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, azure-artifacts

I have created a c++ pipeline where the output of the build pipeline is published to drop container. The structure is the following

```
drop/v1.0.0/Release/MyService.dll
drop/v1.1.0/Release/MyService.dll
drop/v1.1.0/Release/MyService.dll
```

My engineers will need to view drop folder and according to the version that needs to be manually deployed to a client the will download the dll file.

As far as I understand there is not any way to view them under Artifacts (what a shame). I go to the project settings under Storage but I cannot view them either there. Only place that I am able to find them is under the pipeline run and then I have to find in which version of the pipeline run a specific service version was produced. This is a maze. We have dozens of c++ projects and we have to keep track of which pipeline version run of each project matches the service version.
Is there any way to be able to access them like in a folder structure?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Builds - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) via rest API to get all the builds for a pipeline, then use : [Artifacts - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/artifacts/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) rest API to get all the artifacts for a build. It will list all the download URL for artifacts, then you could download them together or choose the one you want to download.

Besides, you could use the publishLocation argument in publish build artifacts task to copy the artifacts to a file share (FilePath). And the file share must be accessible from the agent running the pipeline. In this way you could publish all your artifacts to the file share you want for better management.

In addition, you could also use [Universal Package task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/universal-packages?view=azure-devops) to publish your artifacts to your feed for better review.

Comment: we do not want to write any code. What we need is for our support engineers to be able to view and download the files using a UI like windows explorer structure. Is this something that azure devops support ?